# How to place column name as variable when using Stringindexer in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

```
{simpleDF.columns 
 #output :['color', 'lab', 'value1', 'value2']
 indexer = simpleDF.select('lab')

 from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer
 # Let us create an object of the class StringIndexer
 lblindexer=StringIndexer().setInputCol(indexer).setOutputCol("LabelIndexed")
 idxRes=lblindexer.fit(simpleDF).transform(simpleDF)

 idxRes.show(5)}
```

it is working fine with this line of code but i want it more general

```
 #lblindexer=StringIndexer().setInputCol('lab').setOutputCol("LabelIndexed")
```

getting the  error:
TypeError: Invalid param value given for param "inputCol". Could not convert <class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'> to string type

Comment: Your commented code that doesn't work is passing a string to setInputCol. Does setInputCol take a string? Looks like you got it working when you passed it a simpleDf.select(<a column string>).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the column name for the input col, not a dataframe:

```
lblindexer=StringIndexer().setInputCol('lab').setOutputCol("LabelIndexed")
```

If you want to use a variable,

```
indexer = 'lab'
lblindexer=StringIndexer().setInputCol(indexer).setOutputCol("LabelIndexed")
```

Comment: i want it more generally use thats why it is required to use via variable.

Comment: @AizazYousaf does the second code work for you?

Comment: think like user selected the column from frontend and this column name i want to pass in stringindexer